# How SSH Environment Variables works with shell script file?

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, environment-variables, openssh

If I run the command bellow and my `install.sh` has the following section:

```
export S3_URL=$PRD_URL
export S3_ACCESS_KEY=$PRD_S3_ACCESS_KEY
export S3_SECRET_KEY=$PRD_S3_SECRET_KEY
```

`cat install.sh | ssh $PRD_USER@$PRD_HOST`

The `$PRD_S3_ACCESS_KEY` is going to be resolved from `my host` or the `environment variables` from the remote server?

Comment: Remote. Cat'ting doesn't evaluate the variables in the file.

Comment: @tink Is there any way to evaluate from my host?

Comment: If you rephrase your question above so it matches the comment @philippe's answer below does what you want ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have `gettext` installed (which contains envsubst), you can do

```
envsubst < install.sh | ssh $PRD_USER@$PRD_HOST
```